# If $T$ normal then $T- \lambda I$ normal

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading through these [notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~anne/WQ2007/mat67-Ll-Spectral_Theorem.pdf) and on page 4, they prove that if $T$ is a linear operator with an eigenvalue  $\lambda \in F$ then $\overline{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $T^\ast$ with the same eigenvector. In the proof, they use $T$ normal $\implies T-\lambda I$ normal. Why is this true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As $T$ is normal, we have $TT^* = T^*T$, so we have 
\begin{align}
(T - \lambda I)^*( T - \lambda I) &= T^* T - \bar{\lambda}T  - \lambda T^* + |\lambda|^2 I \\
&= TT^* - \lambda T^* - \bar{\lambda} T + | \lambda|^2 I \\
&= (T - \lambda I)( T - \lambda I)^*.
\end{align}